# How to check if a certain process is running without knowing it's name

Tags: c++, windows

I have a simple C++ program that waits for a certain process to start, but the name of that process could be changed by the user. Is there a way to check if it is running without knowing it's name?

Comment: On which operating system?

Comment: I am doing this on Windows

Comment: You could set up a mutex in one program and check for this in the second

Comment: I would add an option for the user to enter the process name or at least select it from a list the first time..

Comment: It is checking for a malicious program, so that sadly isn't possible.

Comment: You will need to approach this like antivirus and look for some sort of signature in the executable file or behaviour.

Comment: How do you manually identify the process as being the one you're interested in?

Comment: Malwares generally behave in an unusual way, it might be more cpu usage, suspicious disk accesses, high network usage etc.

Comment: How would I get a signature of the file and then check for it? I couldn't find anything about this..

Answer (score 0):

Working with the WinAPI you can check the window class of the given process. Since the name of the process can be changed. "A window class is a set of attributes that the system uses as a template to create a window. Every window is a member of a window class. All window classes are process specific." from [msdn.microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms632596(v=vs.85).aspx)